# Do the coordinates of a Point in MySQL correspond to the longitude, latitude in GoogleMap?

Tags: mysql, geospatial

In GoogleMap there is the latitude and longitude concept of a marker. In MySQL there is the `Point` datatype which has two `coordinates` x and y. I do not know what represents the coordinates of the `Point` ; so I want to know what represent the `coordinates` of a `Point` in accordance to a GoogleMap coordinates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is associating `longitude` with the `x-coordinate` of the map, and `latitude` with the `y-coordinate`.

In the case of `google.maps.LatLng` class the `latitude` coordinate is always written first, followed by the `longitude`. For example,

```
myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -34, lng: 151});
```

But there is also a `google.maps.Point` class, with `x` and `y` as properties, and in this case the `x` is passed first in the class constructor:

```
Point(x, y)
```

Independent of the order of the parameters to be passed, on a two-dimensional plane both `latitude`and `y` coordinates grow in value along a vertical line, and both `longitude` and `x` coordinates grow in value along a horizonal (perpendicular) line.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates